# phpBB 3.0.10 to drupal 7

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have a phpBB 3.0.10 site i want to migrate all the contents of the site to drupal 7.

I want all my users to import from phpBB 3.0.10 to users of drupal 7.

All the forums should be migrated to drupal forums along with their groups and access rules in the phpBB forum.

The users groups should be mentioned.

All the posts and comments should also be imported.

I have tried modules phpbb2drupal and phpbbforum but i was not able to completely migrate it to drupal.

After the migration i will be leaving phpBB 3.0.10 and only be working on drupal 7.

Is there a solution, i have been searching but couldn't find the right solutions.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

use the module [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate), be sure you studied the example and modules like TYPO3_migrate or Wordpress migration.

Migrate has a learning curve, but it is worth it.